# Cors doesnt work in Wamp or Apache

Tags: ajax, apache, tomcat, cors

I spend 2 day of my time in enable CORS in my project with .htaccess or filter in web.xml. but no way doesnt worked for me.
I search in google and do all of the suggestion in stackOverFlow but :(

I have two different ip that i want to send request from one to another with ajax call .
but because of CORS i can not. (error: permission denied to access property Document ).

add the following to .htaccess file and test with curl and it was added to header correctly:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type,X-Requested-    With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST,HEAD, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header add Access-Control-Max-Age "1"
```

Comment: Is the server Apache Tomcat or Apache httpd?

Comment: i test it over apache httpd and wamp in windows @hjpotter92

Answer (score 0):

Are you set up CORS in Javascript AJAX call? 
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

```
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) //safari, chrome, firefox..
  {
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } 
  else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") //internet explorer
  {
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
  } 
  else //chors unsupported
  {
        xhr = null;
  }
```

You can try set up cors in PHP instead .htaccess simple by using

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: thank @Raiper34 for your response. my program is written in extjs. in java  when i use the filter public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFiltert .... it works correctly. but in Extjs it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution for my problem.
I round the CORS with proxyPass in Apache http.conf file.
so locally i config the apache and forward the request to remote server. therefore no CORS accrued.